# Comparison of geospatial support for mongodb and postgis

Tags: postgresql, mongodb, gis, geospatial, postgis

I am in the process of creating a consumer facing location based mobile app that will heavily need GIS support. I have narrowed down the databases to Postgres (PostGIS) and mongodb.

I was wondering how someone who has experience with both would rate the geospatial support particularly in the area of:

1. Performance
2. Query expressibility
3. Precision

Please discuss pro and cons, gotchas and limitations.

Comment: Heavy in what way? Many rows of data, complex queries, many queries per second?

Comment: If you want query performance - MongoDB is very fast at finding resource within a certain radius. If you want expressability and huge array of GIS tools, PostGIS wins by far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could find only a [single page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) of documentation on geospatial queries for mongodb. There are [books](http://www.manning.com/obe/) written about postgis.

If you "heavily need GIS support", then go with postgis - it's a well established and supported solution that's in production in many shops (including mine).

Comment: seth, any limitations you have encountered so far?

Comment: On Postgis? No - it is *extremely* useful.